# What is the difference between "use a class" and "call a class"

Tags: c#

The following description is from the book [*Professional Visual Studio 2017*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=RKA6DwAAQBAJ&pg=SA2-PA6&lpg=SA2-PA6&dq=visual+studio+%22called+by+this+class%22&source=bl&ots=zPKraN3kws&sig=ACfU3U20msTNxfmnhBbkPBRCzOPuyJgOgw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3nd_E0uXjAhWCHM0KHWQCApcQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=visual%20studio%20%22called%20by%20this%20class%22&f=false):

> As you continue navigating into the properties and methods, the context menu >includes Calls, Is Called By, and Is Used By. These options scope the >Solution Explorer to the classes that call this class, classes that are >called by this class, and classes that are used by this class, respectively

What's the difference between "use a class" and "call a class"?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is this from? Do you have a link?

Comment: [I found it](https://books.google.ca/books?id=RKA6DwAAQBAJ&pg=SA2-PA6&lpg=SA2-PA6&dq=visual+studio+%22called+by+this+class%22&source=bl&ots=zPKraN3kws&sig=ACfU3U20msTNxfmnhBbkPBRCzOPuyJgOgw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3nd_E0uXjAhWCHM0KHWQCApcQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=visual%20studio%20%22called%20by%20this%20class%22&f=false)

Comment: Note that the *context* for that excerpt is navigating your code in Visual Studio.  In OOP, it is odd to see anything refer to 'calling a class' because it is more common to think of the objects *created from* those class "blueprints".

Comment: Seems like a rather academic question. Calling is a type of use. Another type of use would be to pass it as an argument or accessing its fields.

Comment: it's useful for me,thanks ! @John Wu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is poorly written, I think. In the first sentence it talks about "navigating into the properties and methods" and the context menu *when you right-click on properties and methods*, but then talks about "this class".

The reality, if you try it out in Visual Studio, is this: If you right-click on a property or method in the Solution Explorer, you get three options:

- Calls: Lists methods that this property or method calls
- Is Called By: Lists methods that use this property or method (and methods that call it - this is pretty handy)
- Is Used By: I'm not totally sure the difference between this and "Is Called By", but it seems to list each line where it's used, including the class that defined the property or method.

Comment: i do think so ↑, but  the description in the book Professional Visual Studio 2017:the classes that call this class, classes that are called by this class, and classes that are used by this class

Comment: It makes me confused

Comment: Me too :) that's why I think it's poorly written. I think they should have used different words to say what they are trying to say.